# Indian won a contest in US. I got 1042-S claiming 30% tax. How to file?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india, non-resident, irs

I won a contest and the sponsor paid the money without withholding tax against my W8BEN. I am Indian citizen and I have to file taxes to US from India. I have received 1042-S claiming that I have to pay 30% Tax.

What is the process to file taxes to IRS from India?

Most material on IRS site refers to how a sponsor or a company can file for 1042-S and how US Citizens can file tax. There is nothing I found points to how a foreign national can file taxes to IRS for the income received from US entity.

Comment: Are you sure you have got the money in your bank account, there are phishing scams out there.

Comment: I got the cheque and encashed it too @Dheer I want to pay the tax. I want to know how to pay 30% tax. I am in India and I don't have SSN in US. Call to IRS talks only about SSN etc.

Comment: https://www.hrblock.in/our-services/us-taxes/us-tax-services-in-india.aspx

Comment: I got to know that I have to apply for ITIN using W7 so far. http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Obtaining-an-ITIN-from-Abroad

For India, there are two IRS certified agents who will process W-7 forms to obtain ITIN

http://www.irs.gov/portal/site/irspup/menuitem.143f806b5568dcd501db6ba54251a0a0/?vgnextoid=eaa4cefba83e9410VgnVCM1000003b4d0a0aRCRD&vgnextchannel=6a082195cc604310VgnVCM1000004e0d010a____

Comment: Found this blog post on Getting ITIN from India
http://chiragr.me/post/27313065938/itin

Comment: Got to know that I have to file 1040NR 
http://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040nre/ch01.html 
http://www.efile.com/tax-form/2014-federal-form-1040nr-us-nonresident-allen-income-tax-return.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to file [IRS Form 1040-NR.](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040nr.pdf) The IRS's website provides [instructions.](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040nr.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

I had to follow these steps

- Apply for ITIN first, takes almost couple of months
- Apply for 1040-NR as recommended by @Heath
- For the delayed process, file penalty + tax